# How to set java system properties Linux

Tags: java, linux

I am triying to set system java properties for proxy. But each time i tried to run the commnad "

> java -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://www-proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80

" just i get the help summarize even for all below:

1. java -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://www-proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80
2. java -Dhttp.proxyHost="http://www-proxy.com" -Dhttp.proxyPort="80"
3. java -Dhttp.proxyHost http://www-proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort 80

running verbose mode i see :

```
[0.007s][info][class,load] java.lang.Error source: shared objects file
[0.049s][info][class,load] java.text.MessageFormat$Field source: jrt:/java.base
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
```

How can i set the above properties without errors. i am using

> java -version openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18 LTS OpenJDK Runtime
> Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.19.0.7-2.0.1) (build 11.0.19+7-LTS) OpenJDK
> 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.19.0.7-2.0.1) (build 11.0.19+7-LTS,
> mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--`java` runs Java code, `-D` sets a system property for the Java code that's being run. You set the properties the way you're doing it--are you expecting them to be persistent somehow?

Comment: I need to reach some dependencies and plugins for opensearch . The pod is getting errors because can't reach the sources. It is a behind a corporate proxy.

Comment: I have not worked so much with java, so i dont undertand if running console command java -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://www-proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 ,  is normal behaivor it shows me the help resume ?
Listing system properties  after running the above commnad i dont  not see them set.

Comment: The `java` command is for running Java code. You are not running Java code, so it's an error. If you need properties set in a (k8s?) pod that's a separate issue (and you may want environment variables, not system properties).